# Using weight paint

Tags: modeling, armature, bones, weight-painting

I have tried some things to make a part move with an armature at a folding line. And it's almost working fine, but due to the mesh it looks a little bit weird when I move one bone upwards in the Pose mode. Downwards it is ok.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this with the weight paint? Or is there another way?

This is the blender file: https://we.tl/t-BmacjXAygR

Comment: the topology of your mesh is very bad, a lot of triangles, some faces are overlaying, some are crossing the fold (therefore your problem), you'd better redo it properly

Comment: Hi how can I change the topology? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sarah, the topology of your mesh is not good, a lot of triangles, some faces are overlaying, some are crossing the fold (therefore your problem), you'd better redo it properly, for example this way, as you can see it can fold in a better way:

[image]